# Method 'get_Properties' in type does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.0

I have a .Net Core 2.0 app which was working absolutely fine. But after some changes I did (I can't identify what exactly) I'm getting error on runtime
[image]

I tried to revert all of my changes, but nothing helps...
All StackTrace I can see:

```
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder..ctor()
   at RODIX.Tacs.Services.Import.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\...\Program.cs:line 10
```

Where should I dig or what can be the problem?
Thanks...

**Update**
This problem disappeared when I changed Core version to 1.1 but still it's not a best solution

Comment: Looks like you need to update Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration to 2.0...

Comment: @CodeCaster But it's not even installed?

Comment: My [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Method+%27get_Properties%27+does+not+have+an+implementation&oq=Method+%27get_Properties%27+does+not+have+an+implementation) all indicate botched updates of core libraries.  Reinstalling the core libraries seemed to solve the problem in the ones I found.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty solid strike against fluent style.  We can't begin to guess which method actually failed.  Posting a screen-shot of it does not make it better question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the references from the older version of your framework. You can do that editing the project file. (.csproj)